# How to call application event handler in init method?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have created an Application event and registered that in Component 'A'. I have component 'B', where i have declared handler for the event. Now my issue is I have the init method on Component 'B' and want to get parameters in this init method. Can anyone suggest approach?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Application Event handlers will necessarily fire *after* the [`aura:valueInit`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:valueInit/documentation) handler (the technical name for the component initialization handler event). The `aura:valueInit` handler is literally the first event that every component receives that your component can respond to. You'll need to write your component in a way that handles this sort of initialization in the Application Event handler, instead.